# Missing dependencies for Django on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy the Google App Engine Django example from https://developers.google.com/appengine/. While trying to run the local development server (`./manage.py runserver`) I've been working through a variety of "missing" Python modules. Generally I've been able to fix the dependency problems by adding various subdirectories below $GOOGLE_APPENGINE_PATH to my $PYTHONPATH. (So far I've added paths to fix the imports for `yaml`, `fancy_urllib`, `ipaddr`, and I'm currently stuck on a broken import for `memcache`).

I'm sick of adding the paths to the Google App Engine modules one-at-a-time as I find problems. Is there a generic solution to this problem that I'm missing? I've done everything exactly as described in the tutorial, and I have main Google App Engine SDK in my Python path (/usr/local/google_appengine). Should I do something else to configure the appropriate paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example (assuming you are using Cloud SQL rather than django-nonrel, which you don't specify) says quite clearly that you should *not* use the Django `runserver`, but the GAE dev server. This is almost certainly the cause of your dependency issues, because the devserver takes care of setting the paths.

Comment: However, the instructions for _Django_ clearly use `./manage.py runserver` not GAE's `dev_appserver.py`. Only the instuctions for Flash and Bottle use GAE's server. This is probably just a typo in the instructions as `dev_appserver.py` is working fine for me.